# Wordpress SVG not showing up anymore

Tags: wordpress, svg

I've worked for weeks on a Wordpress theme (created using Understrap). Everything worked fine, but today when i've launched it i've realised that all my `svg` icons were not showing up. If i try to access it (http://localhost:3000/mywebsite/wp-content/themes/mytheme/img/twitter-footer.svg for example), i'm getting something weird : "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." and below the svg code.

That's the first time i'm getting this error. How can i fix this?

By the way, i haven't installed any new plugins...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your wp-config.php file. However this will be a temprory solution but if it works, you will know the reason of issue.

```
define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true );
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you install SVG supported plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/safe-svg/

Comment: That only helps when you upload svg files directly in the media from the Wordpress back-office, my issue was with svg from a custom `img` folder! I fixed it (see my answer below). But thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i simply opened back my svg files in `Sketch` and re-exported them, it works fine. I think there was an issue with the first export! Problem solved, thanks for the answers though